# XML: Replacing special characters in complete file using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript, special-characters

I was using VBScript to edit some attribute values in several nodes. When I ran script as an output I am getting xml file which uses Character Reference. Is there a way to replace this into Entity Reference using VBScript?

The example of code is this:

```
 Dim xmlDoc, xmlNodes, xmlNodes1, xmlNodes2, xmlNode, bNodeModified , NodeList, Node,strSchema, strName
 Set xmlDoc =  CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

xmlDoc.Async = false
xmlDoc.Load "AT.xml"

Set xmlNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/workbook/datasources/datasource[@name]/connection")
Set xmlNodes1 = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/workbook/datasources/datasource")
Set xmlNodes2 = xmlDoc.selectNodes("/workbook/datasources/datasource[@name]/connection/relation")   
Set NodeList = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/workbook/datasources/datasource[@name]/connection")
bNodeModified = false

If 0 = xmlDoc.parseError Then   

    For Each xmlNode in xmlNodes
        xmlNode.getAttribute("schema") 
        xmlNode.setAttribute "schema", "ABC"    
        xmlNode.getAttribute("username") 
        xmlNode.setAttribute "username", "DEF"
        bNodeModified = true  
    Next

    For Each Node in NodeList
       strSchema = Node.selectSingleNode("@schema").text            
       strName = Node.selectSingleNode("relation/@name").text
       Node.selectSingleNode("relation/@table").text ="["&strSchema&"]"&".["&strName&"]"
    Next

    If bNodeModified Then
        strResult = xmlDoc.save("AT.xsml")
    End If

Else
    WScript.Echo xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If  `
```

Output:

```
<datasource caption="abc" inline="true" name="oracle.42020.48425" version="8.3">
<connection authentication="RDBMS" class="oracle" port="" schema="abc" server="abc" server-oauth="" service="abc" username="abc" workgroup-auth-mode="prompt">
<relation name="abc" table="[abc].[abc]" type="table"/>
...
<attribute datatype="string" name="DebugRemoteType">"SQLT_NUM"</attribute>
```

And I want to get:

```
<datasource caption='abc' inline='true' name='oracle.42020.48425' version='8.3'>
<connection authentication='RDBMS' class='oracle' port='' schema='ABC' server='abc' server-oauth='' service='abc' username='abc' workgroup-auth-mode='prompt'>
<relation name='abc' table='[abc].[abc]' type='table' />
...
<attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;SQLT_NUM&quot;</attribute>
```

To replace characters `"` to `'`, etc...
Tnx in advance!

Comment: Do you  mean (for instance) `&#x22;` (as well as `&#34;`) change to `&quot;` and   `&#160;` (as well as `&#xA0;`) change to `&nbsp;` etc? Or do you need  translate _vbscript's_ `Escape("řečník")` which results to `%F8e%E8n%EDk` and should be e.g. `&rcaron;e&ccaron;n&iacute;k`? Give a short example of input and desired output, please.

Comment: Hi, I've  just eddited my question. Tnx in advance for helping! :)